# Is there a way to generate converted language file via tool (en -> fr etc.)?

Tags: react-intl

I have gone through the react-intl docs but my question is
How to get the converted/desired language in react-intl similar to google translator feature rather than convert manually.

Comment: I think in your case what you need is more related to google translate api than with react-intl. react-intl is a way to provide i18n to your app, but it doesn't translate labels for you. You need to have all translated files and tell the application from which file it should read the labels.

Comment: @Periback: look like you are right, till i find solution.